# How to Have a Table with Left and Right Vertical Boundary Lines but no Vertical Column Delineator?

Tags: tables, columns, ieeeconf

This is how the table declaration looks like.

```
\begin{table*}
\tiny
\centering\caption{Downstream Tasks with MFE and Comparison with Benchmarks}\label{Table:maximum}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\resizebox{\textwidth }{!}{
\begin{tabular}[l]{|lllllllllllll|} % This must be edited, how? 
\hline
% Entries 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
```

I do not want any vertical line between columns, only the left-most and right-most boundary of this nine column table. But in spite of putting a pipe command in the end, I cannot see the right boundary taking effect. This is how the table rendered on a pdf looks like.
[image]
How can I have a table with the right and left boundary, but no other column separator?

If it is important, the document is of IEEETran conference format.

Comment: You all to put all the `&` even in the incomplete row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only 9 columns, you should only declare 9 columns, i.e. `|lllllllll|`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newif\ifShowSol
\ShowSolfalse
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\newtcolorbox{examplebox}[1][]{%
    fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    lowerbox=\ifShowSol visible\else invisible\fi,%
    #1,%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \tiny
    \centering\caption{Downstream Tasks with MFE and Comparison with Benchmarks}\label{Table:maximum}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \resizebox{\textwidth }{!}{
    \begin{tabular}[l]{|lllllllll|} % This must be edited, how? 
    \hline
    Dataset & MFE & Cat-Boost & XGBoost & LGBM & LDA & DCNN & w/o SNA & W/o EDA\\
    1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Make sure that you fill each row s.t. it has nine columns, i.e. even if one of your lines is supposed to have only an entry in the first column, write `Entry & & & & & & & & \\` instead of `Entry\\`.

Obligatory comment: Or forget completly about vertical rules and build your tabular with `booktabs`:)